# PDF file is not opening in Browser I am using Node js

Tags: node.js, post, file-upload, upload, readfile

I am successfully uploading file from DB to server (uploads folder), now i am trying to open file in browser.
Its working on Postman but when i am sending request from FrontEnd it give me 204 status code, and file not opening in browser.

also send this message in console:

> (node:21972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Expected a `target`
> at open (D:\Project\archiwiz\server\node_modules\open\index.js:74:9)
> at D:\Project\archiwiz\server\app.js:111:5
> at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:73:3)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:21972) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:21972) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

front end code:

```
    const openPdf = (imagename) => {
    console.log("in blaaa")
       return 
 fetch(`http://localhost:8080/readFile/uploads/${imagename}`,{

    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/pdf",
      "Content-Type": "application/pdf",

    },



  })

  }
```

backend code:

```
app.post('/readFile/uploads/:filename',  function  (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  console.log("inside Download", req.params.filename)
    fs.readFile(`./uploads/${req.params.filename}`, function (err, filecontent) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err.message)
    }else
    console.log("asladsjajdldlkaalsdj ",filecontent)
    var file =  res.send(filecontent)
    open(file)

  })

  });
```

Kindly suggest me any good solution.

Comment: It seems the error is with open function. Can you add its definition?

Comment: @Anjs Dear : I have no defintion because it is npm package to open file in new tab